# Simplify this double series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

if I have a double sum and I have an expression like

$$ \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{l'=0}^{\infty} g(l)f(l') \frac{1+\cos(\pi(l+l'))}{1+l+l'},$$where g and f are some functions. The thing is: I could evaluate the series over $g$ and over $f$ by their own, but this cosine thing destroys my life.

Is there any chance that I could get rid of the cosine there and convert it into ONE series(maybe by using that this series has only contributions iff $l+l' is even) or TWO, where only f and g appear?(Maybe something like an approximation would help?)

Comment: Would $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{l=0}^{2n} g(l)f(2n-l)\right)\frac{2}{1+2n}$$ be amenable to evaluation?

Comment: $$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{l'=0}^{\infty} g(l)f(l') \frac{1+\cos(\pi(l+l'))}{1+l+l'}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1+\cos(n\pi)}{1+n}\sum_{k=0}^ng(k)f(n-k)$$

Comment: thank you, they both look fine, although not exactly what I wanted, they are still valuable.

Comment: I suspect this was probably your starting point, but just in case it wasn't could you use: $$\int _{0}^{1}\!{x}^{l+k}+ \left( -x \right) ^{l+k}{dx}={\frac {1+
 \left( -1 \right) ^{l+k}}{l+k+1}}$$
and evaluate the integral:$$\int _{0}^{1}\!\sum _{l=0}^{\infty }g \left( l \right) {x}^{l}\sum _{k
=0}^{\infty }f \left( k \right) {x}^{k}+\sum _{l=0}^{\infty }g \left( 
l \right)  \left( -x \right) ^{l}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }f \left( k
 \right)  \left( -x \right) ^{k}{dx}=\int _{0}^{1}\!G \left( x
 \right) F \left( x \right) +G \left( -x \right) F \left( -x \right) {
dx}$$

Comment: no, actually it was not, but this looks very interesting, what exactly are $G$ and $F$?

Comment: $$G \left( x \right) =\sum _{l=0}^{\infty }g \left( l \right) {x}^{l},$$
$$F \left( x \right) =\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }f \left( k \right) {x}^{k}$$ are the generating functions of the coefficients $g(l),f(k)$.

Comment: What are $g(l)$ and $f(k)$? Could you post them up or are they hideous?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2l+1}\left(P_{l+1}(\cos(\alpha))-P_{l-1}(\cos(\alpha))\right)=:f(l)$ and g(l) is pretty much the same and differs from f only in having a constant factor,($P_l$ is the l-th legendre polynomial)

Comment: This looks similar to what you posted in [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138160/how-to-get-an-expression-for-this-integralnumerically-analytically). Are they same?

Comment: You already know that the cosine is immaterial, don't you ?

Answer (score 0):

The cosine is $\pm 1$, while adding $1$ gives $0$ (drop these terms) or $2$ (double the terms with even $l+l'$).